# XNA GraphicsDevice cannot be called from other classes

Tags: c#, xna

everyone!  I'm developing a platformer in XNA/C# and I'm running into problems with GraphicsDevices.  I've heard that XNA requires GraphicsDevices in a lot of methods, but it can only be called after LoadContent() which is problematic for me, as I'm going to have a lot of classes in my project.  How can I get the GraphicsDevice?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here's a code example: http://pastebin.com/vrYhA6MA

Comment: Can you post specific code where you need assistance? Having many classes should not be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Game class, add a GraphicsDeviceManager variable like so:

```
GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
```

Now, in your Game constructor, initialize it like so:

```
graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
```

After the Game constructor, within both the Initialize and the LoadContent methods, the graphics.GraphicsDevice variable should be loaded. You can pass it into methods and give it settings, like DepthStencilState, etc.

Comment: It's already defined in there.  I don't have scope of the Game class from my class, though.  Do I need to inherit from it or instantiate it?  EDIT: Here's my error: 'SMLimitless.Main.graphics' is inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: You really should be inheriting from the Game class and performing everything you need to within there (at the topmost level). That's the normal way XNA works. however, if you want to access that graphics object elsewhere, make it public. To do this, you'll still have to inherit from Game, and make a public GraphicsDeviceManager variable in there.

Answer (score 0):

It has always been my prefered method to pass a reference to the Game object in through the constructors of any other classes. That way I can call

```
this.Texture = game.Content.Load<Texture2d>("Fred");
```

For example.

Comment: Like "using SMLimitless.Game;"?

Comment: Yes I guess. I like to have an interface in the game class that has Update and Draw methods. The Game class just calls those methods on that interface within its own Methods of the same name. What you can do then is just "plug" anything you want into the game, be it a menu or a level. Then in your constructor of any of those items just have a Game object and keep a private reference to it. From then on you can access your Game object and any of its properties that you have made public such as Content etc from within your Level / Menu.